# Adding a system call gives the following error

Tags: linux, kernel

http://xathrya.web.id/blog/2012/10/16/add-new-system-call-to-linux-3-6-1/
I followed all the steps given in the above link. during compilation when i type make module_install i get the following error.

arch/x86/built-in.o:(.rodata+0x5dc): undefined reference to `sys_myfunction'
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
my kernel version is 3.10.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..i got it. Made a silly mistake ..in the implementation part i.e. in the .c file I didnt add ''sys_' .